# Access ArcGIS map created on localhost using JavaScript

Tags: arcgis-server, javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, deployment

I've created an ArcGIS map on my local ArcGIS map server using ArcMap desktop and I am able to open up the map from "View In: ArcGIS Online map viewer". When viewing the map, the url is something like:

`www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A(...etc)` --> simply the local url pointing to the map on my local rest service.

Can I modify this map using JS from here? How should I access this map and what is the map id in this case or do we even need it?

Also when I do `"View In: ArcGIS JavaScript"`, it only shows the frame and the map doesn't come up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the short answer is no.  the [ArcGIS Online map Viewer](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/use-maps/view-maps.htm) is not an application that has been open sourced, and therefore is not customizable.

that being said, we've created a variety of [templated JavaScript applications](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/create-maps/make-your-first-app.htm) that CAN be configured, rehosted, customized and shared.  they are available from the 'share' dialog in the map viewer (with code available on github)